# Bootstrap span's erroneously centered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, centering

I'm laying out a navbar and it's coming out all wrong. I want to have a left and right component so I'm using two span6's. But I'm finding that the first span6 is centered on its own line. Chrome's dev tools show the centered div as having the correct dimensions and 20px left-margin -- it's just centered. As if the container is center it?

Here's the HTML for the navigation view:

```
<div id="group_and_date_controls" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="group_control" class="span12">
          <ul>
            <span id="new_group">New Group</span>
            <li class="controlItem">hi</li>
            <li class="controlItem">hi</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="date_control" class="span6 navbar pull-right">
          <ul id="thing" class="nav pull-right">
            <li>Jun 12th</li>
            <li>Today, Jun 13th</li>
            <li>Jun 14th</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I want to have a left and right component so I'm using two span6's."

...Except if your code is the same as the code you posted in your question, you are using one `span12`, and then one `span6`. Here's a version that uses two `span6` classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/FtPZf/

```
<div id="group_and_date_controls" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="group_control" class="span6">
          <ul>
            <span id="new_group">New Group</span>
            <li class="controlItem">hi</li>
            <li class="controlItem">hi</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="date_control" class="span6 navbar pull-right">
          <ul id="thing" class="nav pull-right">
            <li>Jun 12th</li>
            <li>Today, Jun 13th</li>
            <li>Jun 14th</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```